# Convert schema model nodejs to swagger

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, swagger

I have the following schema model written for nodejs and mongo db, I have to make sure to convert the schema to the swagger format.

As you can see from the diagram, I have a property called "actions" which is an array of strings, this is failing to convert it in the right way.

The code is based on the following project:
[mongoose-to-swagger](https://github.com/giddyinc/mongoose-to-swagger)

Correct way of how it should be converted:

```
"actions": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "create",
              "read",
              "update",
              "delete"
            ]
          }
        }
```

Wrong way of converting it:

```
"actions": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "properties": {//Remove
                    "actions": {//Remove
                      "type": "string",
                      "enum": [
                        "create",
                        "read",
                        "update",
                        "delete"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
```

Schema:

```
const apiKeySchema = new Schema({
  owner: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
  apiKey: String,
  expiration: Date,
  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  scopes: [{
    scope: { type: String, enum: acl.scopes },
    actions: [{ type: String, enum: acl.actions }]
  }]
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
const model = mongoose.model('ApiKey', apiKeySchema)

export const schema = model.schema
export default model
```

modelToSwagger:

```
'use strict';

const adjustType = type => {
  if (type === undefined || type === null) return "Problem";
  let newType = (type === 'ObjectId' || type === 'ObjectID') ? 'object' : type;
  return newType.toLowerCase();
};

function documentModel(Model) {
  const obj = {
    title: Model.modelName,
    properties: {},
    required: []
  };

  const pathsToSchema = (parent, paths) => {
    Object.keys(paths).map(x => paths[x]).forEach(mongooseProp => {
      console.log(mongooseProp.instance, mongooseProp.path)
      if(mongooseProp.instance !== undefined) {
      parent[mongooseProp.path] = {};
        const modelProp = parent[mongooseProp.path];

        if (mongooseProp.instance === 'Array') {
          modelProp.type = 'array';
          modelProp.items = {properties: {}}

          if (mongooseProp.schema) {
            pathsToSchema(modelProp.items.properties, mongooseProp.schema.paths);
          } else if (mongooseProp.caster) {
            let ob = {
              caster: mongooseProp.caster,
              path: mongooseProp.caster.path,
            }
            pathsToSchema(modelProp.items.properties, ob);
          } else {
            modelProp.items = {type: 'object'};
          }
        } else if (mongooseProp.instance === 'Embedded') {
          modelProp.properties = {};
          modelProp.type = 'object';
          pathsToSchema(modelProp.properties, mongooseProp.schema.paths);
        } else if (mongooseProp.instance === 'ObjectID') {
          modelProp.type = 'string';
          modelProp.required = mongooseProp.isRequired || false;
        } else if (mongooseProp.instance === 'Date') {
          modelProp.type = 'string';
          modelProp.format = 'date-time';
          modelProp.required = mongooseProp.isRequired || false;
        } else if (mongooseProp.instance !== undefined) {
          modelProp.type = adjustType(mongooseProp.instance);
          modelProp.required = mongooseProp.isRequired || false;
        }

        // custom mongoose options
        if (mongooseProp.options) {
          if (mongooseProp.options.description) {
            modelProp.description = mongooseProp.options.description;
          }
        }
        if (mongooseProp.enumValues && mongooseProp.enumValues.length) {
          modelProp.enum = mongooseProp.enumValues;
        }
        if (modelProp.required) {
          obj.required.push(mongooseProp.path);
        }
        delete modelProp.required;
      }
    });
  };

  pathsToSchema(obj.properties, Model.schema.paths);

  return obj;
}

documentModel.adjustType = adjustType;
module.exports = documentModel;
```

Use:

```
import m2s from './modelToSwagger'
let definitions = { ApiKeyModel: m2s(apiKey)}
console.log(JSON.stringify({definitions}, null, 2))
```

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: Maybe you could use : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-to-swagger

Comment: @Grammy: I forgot to mention it, the code is that of mongoose-to-swagger, only it didn't work, I just returned {type: 'object'}, so I modified a piece so that it could return the internal objects to me, but there I managed to a certain extent, because I would like an array of strings to come back to me instead I get an array of objects.